# PostgreSQL pgAdmin4 issue "The application server could not be contacted" on Mac

Tags: macos, pgadmin-4

I have installed **pgAdmin4** and it was working fine until I tried to install the newer version (I upgraded from v2.0 to v2.1). Since then I just keep getting the same output.

Comment: What version did you try to upgrade to?

Comment: I had the Pg Admin4 2.0 and i had a popup to go for the 2.1 version, did that and now i cant open it up. The uppgrading progress also was a hussle because i dont think i did it right, now i deleted all of the postgre files and hoping it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run this command

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log restart
```

Then start pgAdmin4, this should fix the issue.